# Apache Hive: Transferring data from existing table to another table

Tags: hadoop, apache-hive

I have multiple existing tables stored in hdfs. I would like to create new tables from the existing external tables so that I can bucket, sort, and compress the data.

What is the proper way to create a table from the existing table?  I could export the existing table to CSV, then create a new table and import it but it seems like there should be a way to import the data directly from the existing table but I haven't found anything in the documentation or via google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some existing table named: `source` and a newly created table named: `target` with fields: `a,b,c,d`

Reading all entries from source and writing to target:

`insert overwrite table target select distinct a,b,c,d from source;`

This works for both internal and external tables.